# rails omniauth and UTF-8 errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, devise, omniauth

I had a recent error using omniauth trying to populate some fields from Google's login

> Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings:
>   ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

```
"omniauth"=>
  {"user_info"=>
    {"name"=>"Joe McÙisnean",
     "last_name"=>"McÙisnean",
     "first_name"=>"Joe",
     "email"=>"someemail@gmail.com"},
   "uid"=>
    "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawnQmfdfsdfsdfdsfsdhGWmuLTiX2Id40k",
   "provider"=>"google_apps"}
```

In my user model

```
  def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    #add some info about the user
    self.email = omniauth['user_info']['email'] if email.blank?
    self.name = omniauth['user_info']['name'] if name.blank?
    self.name = omniauth['user_info'][:name] if name.blank?
    self.nickname = omniauth['user_info']['nickname'] if nickname.blank?
    self.nickname = name.gsub(' ','').downcase if nickname.blank?

    unless omniauth['credentials'].blank?
      user_tokens.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], 
                        :uid => omniauth['uid'],
                        :token => omniauth['credentials']['token'], 
                        :secret => omniauth['credentials']['secret'])
    else
      user_tokens.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
    end
  end
```

I'm not hugely knowledgeable about UTF encoding, so I'm not sure where I should be specifying the encoding?  But I'm guessing it's here before it get's put into the user model and created, I'm unsure what to do about it?

UPDATE:

Rails 3.0.10
Omniauth 0.2.6
Ruby 1.9.2
PG 0.11.0

Default encoding is UTF-8

That didn't seem to be it, so I dug further and found this in the view:

```
Showing /Users/holden/Code/someapp/app/views/users/registrations/_signup.html.erb where line #5 raised:

incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
Extracted source (around line #5):

2:   <%= f.error_messages %>
3: 
4:   <%= f.input :name, :hint => 'your real name' %>
5:   <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => 'Username of your choosing' %>
6: 
7:   <% unless @user.errors[:email].present? or @user.email %>
8:     <%= f.input :email, :as => :hidden %>
```

UPDATE UPDATE:

It seems to be the omniauth gem which is returns the ASCII-8BIT chars, so my next question is how can I parse the hash and convert it back into UTF8 so my app doesn't explode?

`session[:omniauth] = omniauth.to_utf8`

Another part to this crazy ride is when I type this into the console

```
d={"user_info"=>{"email"=>"someemail@gmail.com", "first_name"=>"Joe", "last_name"=>"Mc\xC3\x99isnean", "name"=>"Joe Mc\xC3\x99isnean"}}
```

It automatically converts it to UTF-8, but it explodes when shoved into a session

```
 => {"user_info"=>{"email"=>"someemail@gmail.com", "first_name"=>"Joe", "last_name"=>"McÙisnean", "name"=>"Joe McÙisnean"}}
```

This is a painful nightmare if there ever was one.

Comment: Could you put your versions of rails, ruby and omniauth?

Comment: You can also check the character encoding of a string with `string.encoding.name`.

Comment: done.  I added the versions to my question, and the encoding.name of a working record is "UTF-8"

Comment: Which database gem are you using? If it's mysql, the `mysql2` gem handles utf-8 much better than the others in my experience.

Comment: postgres, using pg 0.11.0, i don't think it's a database issue. it seems to me that for some reason the omniauth data which is getting stored in a session variable is being stored in ASCII-8BIT? But I have no idea how to change this behavior.

Comment: It should depend on your session store, check it in the `session_store` initializer.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking around, how do I force my session_store to use UTF instead of ASCII-8BIT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omniauth proved to be the problem producing the ASCII-8BIT

I ended up forcing the Omniauth hash into submission using:

## omniauth_controller.rb

```
session[:omniauth] = omniauth.to_utf8
```

added recursive method to force convert the rogue ASCII-8BIT to UTF8

## some_initializer.rb

```
class Hash
  def to_utf8
    Hash[
      self.collect do |k, v|
        if (v.respond_to?(:to_utf8))
          [ k, v.to_utf8 ]
        elsif (v.respond_to?(:encoding))
          [ k, v.dup.force_encode('UTF-8') ]
        else
          [ k, v ]
        end
      end
    ]
  end
end
```

Special thanks to tadman

[recursively convert hash containing non-UTF chars to UTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392466/recursively-convert-hash-containing-non-utf-chars-to-utf)