# rails session store and UTF8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, utf-8, session-variables

I'm having a problem involving rails session store and UTF8.  It seems when I save some variable from Omniauth into my session I get ASCII-8BIT afterwards.

I have UTF8 set in my applications.rb file and UFT8 works fine everywhere else.

## application.rb

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

## session_store.rb

```
Wombieapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_wombieapp_session'
```

## in the wild

```
last_name.encoding.name
"UTF-8"
```

Using Rails 3.0.10.

Returning ASCII-8BIT from session

```
omniauth: {"provider"=>"google_apps", "uid"=>"https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?
id=AItOawlx217kz5Tkid0sq5_jIzHGQKupMDI6COc", 
"user_info"=>{"email"=>"someemail@gmail.com", "first_name"=>"Joe", 
"last_name"=>"Mc\xC3\x99isnean", "name"=>"Joe Mc\xC3\x99isnean"}}
```

Should be (original before session):

```
"omniauth"=>
  {"user_info"=>
    {"name"=>"Joe McÙisnean",
     "last_name"=>"McÙisnean",
     "first_name"=>"Joe",
     "email"=>"someemail@gmail.com"},
   "uid"=>
    "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawnQmfdfsdfsdfdsfsdhGWmuLTiX2Id40k",
   "provider"=>"google_apps"}
```

## gemfile

```
#core
gem 'rails', '3.0.10'
gem 'pg', '0.11.0'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'client_side_validations'

#authorization
#gem 'devise', '1.4.2'
gem 'devise', '1.2'
gem 'omniauth', '0.2.6'
gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git', :branch => 'rails-3.0'

#heroku
gem 'heroku'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'resque', '~> 1.17.1', :require => 'resque/server'
gem 'resque-meta', '1.0.3'
gem 'resque-async_deliver'
gem 'resque-heroku-autoscaler', '~> 0.2.3'
```

Also tried adding Encoding to environment.rb

## environment.rb

```
Encoding.default_internal = 'UTF-8'
Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8'

# Initialize the rails application
Wombieapp::Application.initialize!
```

I also tried sticking it in the session manually

```
session[:omniauth] = {"user_info"=> {"name"=>"Joe McÙisnean", "last_name"=>"McÙisnean", "first_name"=>"Joe", "email"=>"someemail@gmail.com"}}
```

and got a ASCII error

```
SyntaxError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#google_apps

/Users/holden/Code/wombie/app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:30: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/Users/holden/Code/wombie/app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:30: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/Users/holden/Code/wombie/app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'
...user_info"=> {"name"=>"Joe McÃ™isnean", "last_name"=>"McÃ™is..
```

Comment: what's your Gemfile? probably some gems override the encoding settings

Comment: I'll add it, but encoding settings for sessions?  UTF8 works everywhere else I know of.  Only gem i could think of would be Omniauth of which I have the latest version.

Comment: You could try to modify http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore and see if there's something wrong here.

Comment: what is Ruby version do you use?

Comment: Did you add the magic comment in your controller file? (`# coding: utf-8`)

Comment: Yeah, I added it to my omniauth controller, the registration controller and to my user.rb file.  No luck, it still comes thru as ASCII-8BIT

Comment: I even tried magic_encoding to change every .rb file to # coding: utf-8

Comment: Did you ever sort this one out? I'm facing now the same issue.

Comment: Seems like you did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349913/rails-omniauth-and-utf-8-errors