# recursively convert hash containing non-UTF chars to UTF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, omniauth

I have a rogue gem (omniauth) which provides a hash of data containing ASCII-BIT8 strings that I would like to convert into UTF.

How can I force all of the string elements of the hash into UTF, as some kind of rails initializer method?  .to_utf8

## initilizer

```
session[:omniauth] = omniauth.to_utf8

class Hash
  def to_utf8
    #not really sure what to do here?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9 you can usually just flip the encoding using the `encode` method. A wrapper around this that recursively transforms the hash, not unlike `symbolize_keys` makes this straightforward:

```
class Hash
  def to_utf8
    Hash[
      self.collect do |k, v|
        if (v.respond_to?(:to_utf8))
          [ k, v.to_utf8 ]
        elsif (v.respond_to?(:encoding))
          [ k, v.dup.encode('UTF-8') ]
        else
          [ k, v ]
        end
      end
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: that looks like it should work perfectly but I'm getting a conversion error from ASCII-8BIT, not sure why.  It worked fine from the console.  Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#google_apps

"\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Comment: That should have a UTF-8 equivalent (Ã) but it seems like this conversion is not supported by default. You may have better luck with this: `v.dup.force_encoding('WINDOWS-1252').encode('UTF-8')`

Comment: That elsif will attempt to dup a symbol and will error in other situations. For me, the following worked better `elsif (v.respond_to?(:force_encoding)) [ k, v.dup.force_encoding('UTF-8') ]`

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
json_string = not_encoded_hash.to_json.dup.encode("UTF-8")
encoded_hash = JSON.parse(json_string).with_indifferent_access
```

Comment: `to_json` on a non-utf8 ruby hash will throw a `source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8`