# Ruby / Mongo - String not valid UTF-8 (BSON::InvalidStringEncoding)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, hash, utf-8

I'm storing large objects which is a giant hash, with nested hashes, arrays, strings, etc. 
There is a very simaliar question to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392466/recursively-convert-hash-containing-non-utf-chars-to-utf). Which gives the following monkey patch:

```
class Hash
  def to_utf8
    Hash[
        self.collect do |k, v|
          if (v.respond_to?(:to_utf8))
            [ k, v.to_utf8 ]
          elsif (v.respond_to?(:encoding))
            [ k, v.dup.encode('UTF-8') ]
          else
            [ k, v ]
          end
        end
    ]
  end
end
```

This answer was great, but doesn't seem to go more than 1 level deep and I am not sure how to refactor it to spider through.

Answer (score 0):

If anyhow possible, rather than fix the symptom, try to fix the problem at the source. Somewhere in your application stack the encoding is skewed. If you can get that fixed, it's probably the most stable and efficient way to go about it.

Otherwise you will have to traverse through your whole MongoDB document and massage the values (don't forget the keys, they are also stored as strings in MongoDB) with what is done here:

```
if text.respond_to?(:to_utf8)
  text.to_utf8
elsif text.respond_to?(:encoding)
  text.encode('utf-8')
else
  text
end
```

I can't help you on how to traverse through your document, for that I would need more information about your model structure and how it is persisted.

**Edit:**

I like this solution, instead of traversing through the model-tree: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15789340/436112. Treat it as a JSON and encode/decode the whole document, fixing the UTF-8 encoding issues in the process